# Fisher's exact test, very small sample size, RxC table, why not work

Tags: statistical-significance

I apply Fisher's exact test on very very small sample size. Each location in the table would have about 1 or 2 samples. The fisher's method has no room to enumerate the the tables, and returns me a very bad result. So is there any other improved exact test for very tiny sample size data?

Comment: How many cells are in the table? (Since the sample size is so tiny, you should have no problem posting the entire table here for our examination.)

Comment: If $R \times C \gg n$ in this sample, then you ought to consider whether the values of $R$ and $C$ can be coded as ordinal or combined in some sane way.

Comment: about 2*8 cells in a table

Comment: In what sense do you mean "fisher's method has no room to enumerate the the tables"?

Comment: I mean for each cell, there is only 1 or 2 or 3 samples in it. The room to enumerate is quite small.

Comment: Was asked previously: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70199/6432

Answer (score 1):

Fisher's exact test gave you right answer based directly on combinatorics. With very small sample you simply cannot reject null hypothesis. But this is not a problem of Fisher's exact test, but the problen of sample size. And there are no field for further improvement of Fisher's exact test, thus, as far as I know, there are no "better" test.